# PostgreSQL trigger doesn't fire

Tags: postgresql

I have an active trigger for myTable which should get fired after insert for each row. When I insert something into myTable by doing:

```
insert into myTable(column1) values(1);
```

The trigger gets fired, however if I insert values with

```
insert into myTable(column1) select column1 from otherTable limit 1;
```

The trigger does not fire at all, even though the value gets inserted into myTable. In my opinion it shouldnt matter which way gets the data inserted into myTable.

This is my trigger ddl

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
  AFTER INSERT 
  ON myTable

FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE myProcedure();
```

Am I not understanding something crucial here?
Oh, and im on PostgreSQL 9.5

Comment: Does the other Table have any rows at all? Also, show us what's inside `myProcedure`

Comment: My guess is that your select doesn't return anything.

Comment: The select does infact return a valid value. I dont mean to be rude, but did you even read my question? The insertation is not the problem here, it succeeds perfectly, its just the fact that the trigger doesnt fire. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: If the trigger fires for the first insert it **will** fire for the second. There must be something you are not telling us and the statement not returning any rows is the most likely cause for this - regardless of what you think the SELECT returns.

Comment: You were right, problem was in my func and im super blind. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name